# How do we save the document by passing the html in POST and not GET?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have added the ["save" plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/save). By default, once the plugin is installed & is working, I see that it tries to save the text by passing it in a **GET** mode. How do we make it to do the same in **POST** mode ? It would be much more sensible in saving the document in **POST**.

I cannot see where to customize the plugin and cannot find any documentation on customizing the plugin.

I am using ckeditor, Version 4.4.2 • 24 Jun 2014, and added the plugin for "save".

Comment: Is your textarea (which CKEditor binds to) in a <form>? If so, does changing the form method from GET to POST not do the trick?
 
"Second, change the method of your form to POST instead of get." - http://ckeditor.com/comment/59663#comment-59663

Comment: @DaveSalomon Ok, thanks silly me. Adding "method=POST" did the trick.

Comment: Glad it worked maan. Please consider accepting one of the answers - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Switch your <form> tag to use method="POST".

Answer (score 0):

Modifying  `<form>` to `<form method="POST">` did the trick. I was expecting it to be done by default, as I could not find any documentation on it.